# Dropdown item in navbar

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a></li>
        @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
        {
            **<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="ProgressDropDown">
                    @ProgressResources.Progress
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="ProgressDropDown">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Progress" asp-action="Index">@ProgressResources.View</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Progress" asp-action="Create">@ProgressResources.Create</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>**
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a "Progress" dropdown in a navbar which would essentially have the View and Create actions as the dropdown items (in a .cshtml file)

I will posted all my navbar

I am expecting this code to create this dropdown nav bar, but instead, it creates only the dropdown item, but nothing happens when I click it. I checked inspect element for errors, but I couldn't find any. It should show only when a user is signed in.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or Tailwind? It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

> it creates only the dropdown item, but nothing happens when I click
> it.

Try to add below code in your program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
...
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

result:
[image]

**Update**

After test your project, I find you have Index view, Privacy view not Razor page, you can change below :

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a></li>
```

into:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" >Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a></li>
```

Besides, you need to delete `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>` from your _Layout.cshtml, because you already have  `<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`

result: (I create the ProgressController Index view and Create view based your project)

[image]

Comment: Those lines of code are already added. First one is the first line after var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); and the second one is between app.UseAuthorization(); and app.Run();

Comment: Hi@EasyPeasy  , I put your code in _LoginPatial.cshtml , and it works fine, it's strange why you add above code but creates only the dropdown item, but nothing happens when  click it.  Can you go to the Index view of Progress by the url ?

Comment: Yes.  Both Create and Index pages work actually. I am not sure if this helps, but after a closer look, I noticed that the arrow down thingy of the dropdown becomes slightly darker after clicking it and never to "recover" unless a page refresh happens - this I guess means that the click is recognized by the application...

Comment: @EasyPeasy  , If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage. You can build a small demo and share it via gihub .

Comment: https://github.com/bogdanciuciuc/demo_navbar.git

Comment: Hi @EasyPeasy , please  have a look at my update.

Comment: How do I find it? I see no comments, commits, branches forks or pull requests. Could you please send a link? and thank you a lot for checking it out!

Comment: @EasyPeasy,  I update in my answer. You can go to the Default.cshtml of the Navigation folder make some change as above, and in  _Layout.cshtml, delete the `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>` .